# Spring boot how to test WebServerInitialized event

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I am trying to test functionality in an application that occurs when the app registers with a service registry.  This happens only when the app has a full web context (ie. `spring-boot-starter-web` is on the class path, and the servlet is not mocked).  This is controlled via `spring-cloud-commons` [AbstractAutoServiceRegistration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/AbstractAutoServiceRegistration.java).

## Simple Test

All the test should do is the following:

```
1) Bring up Web App
2) Verify auto-registration w/ service registry event fired
3) Manually force close app
4) Verify auto-deregistratoin occurred
```

### Approach 1: @SpringBootTest

`SpringBootTest` makes it easy to create the full web context, which is great.  But I cannot close the app mid-test to force a deregister

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = MyAutoConfig.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DiscoverySpringCloudBootMinimalRegistrationTest {

@Test
public void register_deregister {
    // Force-close app to trigger dereigster (causes exception)
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();

    verify(registry, times(1)).register(autoRegistrationServiceRecord);
    verify(registry, times(1)).deregister(autoRegistrationServiceRecord);
}
```

The `context.close()` call results in a long error, basically saying not to manually close the context like this.

```
..... contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]] is not active. This may be due to one of the following reasons: 1) the context was closed programmatically by user code; 2) the context was closed during parallel test execution either according to @DirtiesContext semantics or due to automatic eviction from the ContextCache due to a maximum cache size policy.
```

### Approach 2: WebContextRunner

In this approach, I avoid `@SpringBootTest` and manually configure a context runner.  This works nicely for calling `context.close()` but the web context in configures has a mock servlet, and DOES NOT trigger the `WebInitializedEvent` required for autoregistration.

```
public class BasicAutoConfigTests {

    private WebApplicationContextRunner runner;

    @Test
    public void register_deregister() {

       runner = new WebApplicationContextRunner()
              .withConfiguration(
                    AutoConfigurations.of(MyAutoConfig.class));


       runner.run((context) -> {
          assertThat(context).hasNotFailed();

          ServiceRegistry registry = context.getBean(ServiceRegistry.class);
          ServiceRecord autoRegistration = context.getBean(MyServiceRecord.class);
          context.close();

          verify(registry, times(1)).register(autoRegistration);
          verify(registry, times(1)).deregister(autoRegistration);

      });
  }
```

**This almost works** but results in a `MockServletContext` bean, which I presume is failing to trigger the requisite `WebServerInitializedEvent` from `spring-cloud-commons`.  How can this approach bootstrap an authentic, complete embedded tomcat server?

Comment: It's very much an integration test. In some cases in spring cloud, we found the best thing to do is `SpringApplication.run()`.

Comment: You would do this from within `@SpringBootTest`?  And if so, how would you structure your `verify` on app deregister?  Would you still call `app.close()` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Spencer's advice, I used the spring application builder to create a full web app.  I also did this outside of the autoconfiguration module - created a new maven submodule called "integration tests" with `spring-boot-starter-web` on the classpath.

```
@Import(MyAutoConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MinStarterBasicApp {

@Bean
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry() {
    return mock(ServiceRegistry.class);
    }

    static ConfigurableApplicationContext setupWebApp(String... profiles){
        System.setProperty("spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding", "true");

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MinStarterBasicApp.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
                .profiles(profiles)
                .build();
        return app.run();
    }
}
```

Where `profiles` allows me to pass in a application.properties files by name as shown below.  Also it's important to make sure we manually `close` the app context for each test.

```
public class StarterBasicAutoconfigTest {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (context != null && context.isRunning())
            context.close();
    }


    @Test
    public void sometest() {
        context = MinStarterBasicApp.setupWebApp("profile1");

        ServiceRegistry registry = context.getBean(ServiceRegistry.class);
        context.close();

        Mockito.verify(registry, times(1)).register(any());
        Mockito.verify(registry, times(1)).deregister(any());
}
```